# Writing in the form a+bi for $e^{3+i}$ is it the right answer?

Tags: complex-analysis

$e^{3+i}$ = $e^3e^i$

so solving it would be $e^3 + 0i$ right?

Sorry, haven't touched maths for 2years and forgot even basic ones..

Comment: What does $i$ denote here?

Comment: Almost surely it denotes $\sqrt{-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$e^{3+i}=e^{3}(\cos 1+i \sin 1)$.

Comment: Oh I thought it would be $e^3(cos 0 - i sin 0)$  I was so wrong
Thank you!